# print out max and min numbers of the input

Tags: python

I'm asked to write a program which takes in a bunch of numbers and print out the maximum and minimum number of them, below is my code:

```
maximum = None
minimum = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == 'done':
        break;
    try:
        num = int(num)
        if num >= maximum:
            maximum = num
        if num <= minimum:
            minimum = num
    except:
        print "Please Enter A Number!"
        continue
print "Max = ",maximum, "Min = ",minimum
```

The thing is when I run this program the Min always equals to its initial value None, but it will work if I change the second if statement into else. What's wrong with the current one?

Comment: only `except` what you want to `except`.  In your case you want `except ValueError:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indentation is correct in the question (and not some copy paste mistake, that is the issue, the `minimum = num` line needs to be indented towards the right. Also, you need to take care of maximum and minimum being `None` that would throw error when used in comparison to `int` in Python 3.x , and would not work correctly for minimum in Python 2.x since no int would be smaller than None.

```
maximum = None
minimum = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == 'done':
        break;
    try:
        num = int(num)
        if maximum is None:
            maximum = num
            minimum = num
        if num >= maximum:
            maximum = num
        if num <= minimum:
            minimum = num
    except:
        print "Please Enter A Number!"
        continue
print "Max = ",maximum, "Min = ",minimum
```

Comment: No, it doesn't give an error. None can actually be compared with ints. Try it.

Comment: Is that something in Python 2.x ? I tried in Python 3.4 and got -
`>>> -100 < None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()`

Comment: Anyway if he uses None. it would not work for minimum right?

Comment: It is a typo, thanks for point out. But I still don't understand how come I can compare None to a larger number but can't compare it to a smaller number?

Comment: Because internally None is smaller than all numbers* , though this is not true for Python version 3 + , there you get error when comparing none and int . Also, when trying to take minimum or maximum of a list of numbers, its always advisable to put the first number in the list as the starting minimum or maximum, because , assume you gave some arbitrary number as minimum (lets say 0 for example , though that is a bad choice for minimum) and you do not input any number lesser than that, then you would get `0` as the minimum, even thoug it does not exist in the list of numbers

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, even if I changed the second if to else it won't work either. But I thought it would work since I have this if-else structure, either one block will be executed. Could you tell me y?

Comment: Because when you change the if to else, it would make minimum as the last number you enter after the highest maximum.
Please note that if the number is not maximum it is minimum (that is the logic you get by doing if-else,but that is not correct , is it?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
track = []
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print "Please Enter A Number!"
        continue
    track.append(num)

print "Max = ", max(track), "Min = ", min(track)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem here is with your use of `None` here as the default value. It happens to work for the maximum because all numbers are greater than `None`. However, that way the minimum condition will *never come true*.

There are a few ways to fix this. The obvious and non-pythonic way is to set the minimum to `float('inf')`. This is kinda obviously infinity. The "better" way would be to change the condition to:

```
if num <= minimum or minimum==None:
```

which will automatically set the min on the first pass.

P.S.: I'm guessing you're doing this for algo-practice, because `min()` and `max()` functions are built-in.

Comment: So you mean no number will ever be evaluated smaller than None? That's kinda weird... I mean obviously None is smaller than some number so that the first if will get executed

Comment: @Enkri_ Nope. Try `float('-inf')<None` in your terminal. That's why you need the `or num==None` for the first pass of the loop.

Comment: I tried to type it in my terminal but I got "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'-inf'". Also I think it should be minimum == None instead of num==None?

Comment: @Enkri_ yup that's what I meant, sorry. And I didn't mean your literal terminal but the pythonn terminal.